# Trouble with Adsense ads showing up on my site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, adsense

I implemented google AdSense ads on my site, and they showed up one time. I never saw them again. If you inspect my site, you can see that the ads are there and the script tags in the ad areas, but they just aren't showing up. If you inspect element on the right part of the header for instance, you'll see  but it is grayed out. Do you have to create a new ad unit for each ad space on your site, or do you create one ad unit for your whole site and just use that code on all the ad spaces on your site? Any help is really appreciated!

[My Site](http://www.mosthood.com)

Comment: Do you have any ad blocker extensions installed in your browser?

Comment: I do, but not on internet explorer or edge but they still don't show up when I use those browsers. I removed robots.txt from my site also

Comment: Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: Yes it didn't display anything

Comment: When I inspect the ad elements, I see that the correct ad unit ID is in the code. I just don't understand why they aren't showing up.

Comment: They show for me. Did you check the adsense stats? If you refresh your own pages to often (while testing and stuff), you won't see your own ads after a while. Adsense shows a number of ads per IP per timeslot.